# Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.4 - Error when building Flutter app on mac m1

Tags: flutter, protocol-buffers

When compiling build for Flutter on mac m1 - I receive this error

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:mfgDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.4/protobuf-javalite-3.17.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.4/protobuf-javalite-3.17.4.pom
       - https://storage.googleapis.com/download.flutter.io/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.4/protobuf-javalite-3.17.4.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.4/protobuf-javalite-3.17.4.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :flutter_blue
```

Comment: There appears to be no 3.17.4 (see [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-javalite/3.17.3/index.html) and [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-javalite)). Can you determine what package is specifying 3.17.4 as the version? You may want to try bumping to a more recent version. 3.17.x was June 2021 and currently 4.0.x.